# Auto upload image on canvas without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js i am trying to upload image on canvas without submit button ,image is uploading successfully but the problem is that when i upload one image its uploading 4 time's on canvas  just let me know how do i break the loop once count==1

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
 $('#preview').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
      // alert('NotChanged');
      var count=0;
      var gal_id =$(this).children('img').attr('id');

        if(gal_id=='upload')

            {
                count++;

       // alert(count);
       // alert(gal_src);
           }
            if(count==1)
          {
                   //var gal_id =$(this).children('img').attr('id');
 var imgInstance2 = new fabric.Image(gal_id, {
  left: 300,
  top: 200,
 // height:100,
  angle: 60
 // opacity: 0.85
});
 // add image onto canvas
  canvas.add(imgInstance2);

   parent.$("#upload_image_pop_up").bPopup().close();


           }



    })
}
```

You can see here one image attached 4 times.
[image]

Comment: I think you are binding it to multiple events, so each event invokes the function and ads the picture

Comment: How do i  bind single event?? @lombausch

Comment: ... bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved',... you are binding 3 events there. I don't know how do you invoke them, but I suspect somewhere there is your problem.

Comment: If you want to stop after you inserted the image once, you should make sure that you don't initialize `count` with every call to the event handler. `count` should be defined and initialized outside of the event handler

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer following is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    var flag=0;
    $('#preview').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
        //$('#preview').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
        if(flag==0)
            {
  // $('#preview').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
      // alert('NotChanged');
      var count=0;

      var gal_id =$(this).children('img').attr('id');
       var gal_src =$(this).children('img').attr('src');
        if(gal_id=='upload')

            {
                count++;


       // alert(count);
       // alert(gal_src);
           }
            if(count==1)
          {
                   //var gal_id =$(this).children('img').attr('id');
 var imgInstance2 = new fabric.Image(gal_id, {
  left: 300,
  top: 200,
 // height:100,
  angle: 60
 // opacity: 0.85
});
 // add image onto canvas
  canvas.add(imgInstance2);

   parent.$("#upload_image_pop_up").bPopup().close();
       flag=1;     

           }


            }       
    })
```